# Не получается отправить requests.post запрос на страницу

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, bs4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 
Firefox/66.0",
    "Accept-Encoding": "*",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
}
datas = {
    "makeme": "yes",
    "ystext": "Атака титанов",
}
s = requests.Session()
rs = s.post("https://jut.su/search/", data=datas, headers=headers)
https = BS(rs.text, 'lxml')
print(https)
```

Вроде делаю всё правильно, но после отправки запроса я должен перейти на другую страницу, а в ответ получаю http форму страницы на которую отправляется запрос. Помогите пожалуйста советом, очень хочу разобраться

Comment: Не понимаю о какой странице вы говорите, запросы нужны для получения какого-то ответа от сервера, что вы и получаете в данном случае. С помощью [online запросы](https://reqbin.com/) проверил ваш запрос и он корректный. Сформулируйте более конкретный вопрос

Comment: @Ara_Bog вопрос как бы правильный, задающий просто не стал вдаваться в подробности. А где вы проверяли случайно Status: 200 (OK)?

Comment: @СергейШашко ссылку прикрепил в комментарии

Comment: Ян Милый resp.status_code  200 или 301?